# filtering and make a list of lists from a csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which looks like the small example:

small example:

```
Id  sv  item1   item2   item3
pos ab  4   5   8
reg ad  7   85  96
neg af  14  78  32
neg ab  47  5   6
```

I would like to make a list of lists in python from this csv file. I want to skip the first 2 columns and then look for "`neg`" in the "`Id`" column. if the value in "Id" is "neg" I want to put the value of every row for the `non-skipped` columns in a inner list and make a list of lists using all `inner lists`. 
for the small example the last 2 rows of the "`Id`" column are "`neg`" so I will take only these rows. then I will skip the 1st 2 columns therefore we would have 3 columns left. that is why the results would be a list of lists with 3 inner lists.
here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
results = [[14, 47], [78, 5], [32, 6]]
```

to get this results I wrote the following code in python but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

```
with open("infile.txt") as f:
    df = f.loc[f["Id"] == "neg"]
    results = []
    for line in df:
        results.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `csv` module

**Ex:**

```
import csv

results = []
with open(filename, "rU") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == 'neg':
            results.append(list(filter(None, row[2:])))

print([i for i in zip(*results)])
```

**Output:**

```
[('14', '47'), ('78', '5'), ('32', '6')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

results = df[df.Id.eq('neg')].iloc[:,2:].values.T.tolist()

print(results)
[[14, 47], [78, 5], [32, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use pandas and numpy both for this!**

**One line solution**

```
df=df.read_csv("infile.csv")
results=np.transpose(df[df['Id']=='neg'][['item1','item2','item3']].values).tolist()
```

Result would be

```
[[14, 47], [78, 5], [32, 6]]
```

**Explained in detail:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv("infile.csv")
df=df[df['Id']=='neg'] #filter dataframe where Id is equal to 'neg'
df=df[['item1','item2','item3']] #select only item1,item2,item3 columns
df=df.values #Return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame.
transposed=np.transpose(df) #Permute the dimensions of an array.
results=transposed.tolist() #returns a python list datastructure
print(results)
```

You can read more about all the methods use here

- [df.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)
- [np.transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)
- [np.tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)